# Automatize conversion .wrl to .fbx (or .obj) using Blender

Tags: python, batch-file, blender

I want to convert automatically a catia file to a .fbx or .obj. I can convert a .stl to a .obj using this code :

Python code :

```
import bpy
import sys


argv = sys.argv
argv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:] # get all args after "--"

stl_in = argv[0]
obj_out = argv[1]

#Importing the file
bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=stl_in, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')
#Exporting the file
bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=obj_out, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')
```

Batch to launch :

```
@echo off

set PATH=C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender

set FILENAME=object.stl

set TARGET=object.obj

blender --background --python convert_stl_to_obj.py -- %FILENAME% %TARGET%
```

And it work perfectly, BUT using the same code for a wrl to an obj or fbx is not working :

Python code :

```
import bpy
import sys

argv = sys.argv
argv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:] # get all args after "--"

wrl_in = argv[0]
obj_out = argv[1]

bpy.ops.import_scene.x3d(filepath=wrl_in, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')

bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=obj_out, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')
```

Batch :

```
@echo off

set PATH=C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender

set FILENAME=assemblage.wrl

set TARGET=assemblage.obj

blender --background --python convert_wrl_to_obj.py -- %FILENAME% %TARGET%
```

I don't understand why, i got error from blender

> found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.77\python Error: Array length mismatch (got 108,
>   expected more) Error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Program Files\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d__init__.py", line 81, in execute
>       return import_x3d.load(context, **keywords)   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d\import_x3d.py", line 3597, in load
>       global_matrix=global_matrix,   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d\import_x3d.py", line 3494, in load_web3d
>       importShape(bpyscene, node, ancestry, global_matrix)   File "C:\Program Files\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d\import_x3d.py", line 3118, in importShape
>       bpydata = geom_fn(geom, ancestry, bpyima)   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d\import_x3d.py", line 1950, in importMesh_IndexedFaceSet
>       bpymesh.vertices.foreach_set("normal", co) RuntimeError: internal error setting the array
>
> location: C:\Program Files\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\modules\bpy\o ps.py:189
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d__init__.py", line 81, in execute
>       return import_x3d.load(context, **keywords)   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d\import_x3d.py", line 3597, in load
>       global_matrix=global_matrix,   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d\import_x3d.py", line 3494, in load_web3d
>       importShape(bpyscene, node, ancestry, global_matrix)   File "C:\Program Files\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d\import_x3d.py", line 3118, in importShape
>       bpydata = geom_fn(geom, ancestry, bpyima)   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d\import_x3d.py", line 1950, in importMesh_IndexedFaceSet
>       bpymesh.vertices.foreach_set("normal", co) RuntimeError: internal error setting the array
>
> location: C:\Program Files\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\modules\bpy\o ps.py:189
>
> location: C:\Program Files\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\modules\bpy\o ps.py:189 Error:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d__init__.py", line 81, in execute
>       return import_x3d.load(context, **keywords)   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d\import_x3d.py", line 3597, in load
>       global_matrix=global_matrix,   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d\import_x3d.py", line 3494, in load_web3d
>       importShape(bpyscene, node, ancestry, global_matrix)   File "C:\Program Files\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d\import_x3d.py", line 3118, in importShape
>       bpydata = geom_fn(geom, ancestry, bpyima)   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d\import_x3d.py", line 1950, in importMesh_IndexedFaceSet
>       bpymesh.vertices.foreach_set("normal", co) RuntimeError: internal error setting the array
>
> location: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Traceback (most recent
>   call last):
>
> File "", line 2, in    File
>   "C:\Users\abadie-moreau\Documents\Migration Catia to
>   Unity\Migration_STL_ to_Obj\convert_wrl_to_obj\convert_wrl_to_obj.py",
>   line 10, in 
>       bpy.ops.import_scene.x3d(filepath=wrl_in, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')   File "C:\Program Files\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\modules\bpy\ops .py", line 189, in
>   **call**
>       ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw) RuntimeError: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d__init__.py", line 81, in execute
>       return import_x3d.load(context, **keywords)   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d\import_x3d.py", line 3597, in load
>       global_matrix=global_matrix,   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d\import_x3d.py", line 3494, in load_web3d
>       importShape(bpyscene, node, ancestry, global_matrix)   File "C:\Program Files\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d\import_x3d.py", line 3118, in importShape
>       bpydata = geom_fn(geom, ancestry, bpyima)   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene
>   _x3d\import_x3d.py", line 1950, in importMesh_IndexedFaceSet
>       bpymesh.vertices.foreach_set("normal", co) RuntimeError: internal error setting the array
>
> location: C:\Program Files\Blender
>   Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\modules\bpy\o ps.py:189
>
> ... truncated Blender quit

If somedy have a clue of where i'm doing wrong, i'll be more than happy.

Thank you for your time !

Comment: My first guess would be the file is not being read correctly, can you open the failing file in something else like meshlab? Provide a sample file to test with?

Comment: Hello sambler, thank you for the reply.
The file is readable in blender when i open it manually with no problem. I can import it from an .wrl and export it to .fbx or .stl. My problem is to automatize so that the user don't have to do it manually. It's working with a .stl but not with a .wrl